# Do you know an open source version of Etherpad?

Tags: collaboration

We need to implement a real time code collaboration. With all the functionalities that exist on Etherpad (version control, timeslider etc).

Do you know an open source project that we can give us a head start ? Or a tutorial on best practices about real time collaboration online ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, their [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/) project.

Answer (score 0):

The code repo is [now on github](https://github.com/ether/pad)